# Error on starting project with TypeORM for spanner database

Tags: node.js, typeorm, nest, google-cloud-spanner

I was trying to connect to spanner database using TypeORM, but configuration initial project generated didn't work for me.

So I was starting from documentation and ran those commands.

```
    npm install typeorm -g

    typeorm init --name MyProject --database spanner

    npm i
    
    npm start
```

as a result it generated me this AppDataSource in data-source.ts

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
        type: "spanner",
        projectId: "test",
        instanceId: "test",
        databaseId: 'test',
        synchronize: true,
        logging: false,
        entities: [User],
        migrations: [],
        subscribers: [],
    })
```

I replaced "test" with values that worked for me while connecting to spanner through @google-cloud/spanner lib. Should it be smith different? In docs there is (code below) but I believe those comments about values are wrong.

```
export interface SpannerConnectionCredentialsOptions {
        /**
         * Connection url where perform connection to.
         */
        readonly instanceId?: string;
        /**
         * Database host.
         */
        readonly projectId?: string;
        /**
         * Database host port.
         */
        readonly databaseId?: string;
    }
```

also I exported GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in terminal where I ran those commands, but as a result there was an error

```
    /projects/hg/MyProject/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/build/src/index.js:468
                throw new google_gax_1.GoogleError('A name is required to access an Instance object.');
                      ^
    GoogleError: A name is required to access an Instance object.
        at Spanner.instance
```

Did anyone actually used some sort of ORM for spanner database? Maybe there is an alternative for TypeORM?

Answer (score 0):

What you've done looks correct and should be working. I followed the [TypeORM Quick Start](https://typeorm.io/#quick-start) guide myself and was able to successfully run `npm start` after making a small patch to generate the user ID manually and after updating `projectId`, `instanceId`, and `databaseId`.

For reference, I uploaded my generated project to https://github.com/c2nes/typeorm-spanner-quick-start. Perhaps you can find a difference between your sample project and mine.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34886881)